# Deadlock issues caused by concurrent read and write of rust?

Tags: sockets, rust, concurrency, transport

How to solve the problem of using blocking sockets to separate reads and writes between different threads during concurrent reads and writes of rust, where threads share data (transport or socket) and use arcto cause deadlocks?

here is a simple example.

application client write by rust:

```rust
use std::env;
use std::io::{Error, Read, Write};
use std::net::{TcpStream, ToSocketAddrs};
use std::ptr::eq;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time::sleep;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct TcpTransport {
    pub conn: TcpStream,
}

impl TcpTransport {
    fn send_packet(&mut self, data: &[u8]) -> Result<(), Error> {
        self.conn.write_all(data)?;
        Ok(())
    }

    fn read_packet(&mut self) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Error> {
        let mut lenbuf = [0u8; 2];
        self.conn.read_exact(&mut lenbuf)?;

        let length = (lenbuf[0] as usize) << 8 | lenbuf[1] as usize;
        let mut databuf = vec![0u8; length];
        self.conn.read_exact(&mut databuf)?;

        Ok(databuf)
    }

    fn close(&self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        println!("close transport");
        self.conn.shutdown(std::net::Shutdown::Both)?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

pub fn new_tcp_transport(host: &str, port: u16) -> Result<TcpTransport, Error> {
    let socket_addr = (host, port).to_socket_addrs()?.next().unwrap();
    let conn = TcpStream::connect_timeout(&socket_addr, Duration::from_secs(10))?;
    Ok(TcpTransport { conn })
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // tsport Arc<Mutex><dyn Transport+Send+sync>
    let tsport = new_tcp_transport("127.0.0.1", 4000).unwrap();
    let tsport = Arc::new(Mutex::new(tsport));
    let tsport1 = tsport.clone();
    let tsport2 = tsport.clone();
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        println!("read worker started");
        'read_loop: loop {
            // sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
            println!("read exec here===");
            let packet = match tsport1.lock().unwrap().read_packet() {
                Ok(packet) => packet,
                Err(err) => {
                    eprintln!("Transport read packet error: {:?}", err);
                    break 'read_loop;
                }
            };
            println!("read packet{:?}", packet);
        }
        println!("read worker stoped");
    });
    let _=tokio::spawn(async move {
        println!("write worker started");
        'writeloop: loop {
            sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
            println!("write exec here===");
            let mut ts = tsport2.lock().unwrap();
            let data = vec![0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4];
            if let Err(er) = ts.send_packet(&data) {
                eprintln!("Transport write packet error: {:?}", er);
                break 'writeloop;
            }
            println!("send packet success.");
        }
        println!("write worker stoped");
    }).await;
}
```

application server write by nodejs:

```js
var net = require('net');
net.createServer(function(socket){
    socket.on('data', function(data){
        console.log("server recv data:",data);
    });
}).listen(4000);

console.log('server listen 127.0.0.1:4000');
```

cargo.toml

```ini
[package]
name = "readwrite"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.28.1", features = ["full"] }
```

application client write by nodejs:

```js
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(4000, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    setInterval(() => {
        var data = Buffer.from("hello server");
        var datalen = data.length;
        console.log('client write===');
        client.write(Buffer.concat([Buffer.from([datalen >> 8, datalen % 256]), data]));
    }, 1000);

});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('client received: ',data);
});
```

Comment: recver.lock() is taken before tsport2.lock() If it is taken somewhere under other lock, which is taken under tsport.lock(), it may cause deadlock

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The code must be embedded in the question. External links are not enough.

Comment: Nitpick: The `unsafe impl Send` is completely redundant, `TcpStream` is already `Send`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that `&TcpStream` (a reference to `TcpStream`) also implements `Read` and `Write`:

```rust
impl TcpTransport {
    fn send_packet(&self, data: &[u8]) -> Result<(), Error> {
        (&self.conn).write_all(data)?;
        Ok(())
    }

    fn read_packet(&self) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Error> {
        let mut lenbuf = [0u8; 2];
        (&self.conn).read_exact(&mut lenbuf)?;

        let length = (lenbuf[0] as usize) << 8 | lenbuf[1] as usize;
        let mut databuf = vec![0u8; length];
        (&self.conn).read_exact(&mut databuf)?;

        Ok(databuf)
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let tsport = new_tcp_transport("127.0.0.1", 4000).unwrap();
    let tsport = Arc::new(tsport);
    let tsport1 = tsport.clone();
    let tsport2 = tsport.clone();
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        println!("read worker started");
        'read_loop: loop {
            // sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
            let packet = match tsport1.read_packet() {
                Ok(packet) => packet,
                Err(err) => {
                    eprintln!("Transport read packet error: {:?}", err);
                    break 'read_loop;
                }
            };
            println!("read packet{:?}", packet);
        }
        println!("read worker stoped");
    });
    let _ = tokio::spawn(async move {
        println!("write worker started");
        'writeloop: loop {
            // sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
            let data = vec![0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4];
            if let Err(er) = tsport2.send_packet(&data) {
                eprintln!("Transport write packet error: {:?}", er);
                break 'writeloop;
            }
            println!("send packet success.");
        }
        println!("write worker stoped");
    })
    .await;
}
```

But your code is incorrect because you must never, ever, block in async context. And std's `TcpStream` is blocking. You need to use [`tokio`'s `TcpStream`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html). It does not implement `AsyncRead` or `AsyncWrite` for references, but `tokio` has [`tokio::io::split()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/fn.split.html) to split an `AsyncRead + AsyncWrite` into halves:

```rust
use std::io::Error;
use std::time::Duration;

use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt, ReadHalf};
use tokio::net::TcpStream;

pub async fn new_tcp_transport(host: &str, port: u16) -> Result<TcpStream, Error> {
    let connect_fut = TcpStream::connect((host, port));
    let conn = tokio::time::timeout(Duration::from_secs(10), connect_fut).await??;
    Ok(conn)
}

async fn read_packet(conn: &mut ReadHalf<TcpStream>) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Error> {
    let mut lenbuf = [0u8; 2];
    conn.read_exact(&mut lenbuf).await?;

    let length = (lenbuf[0] as usize) << 8 | lenbuf[1] as usize;
    let mut databuf = vec![0u8; length];
    conn.read_exact(&mut databuf).await?;

    Ok(databuf)
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // tsport Arc<Mutex><dyn Transport+Send+sync>
    let tsport = new_tcp_transport("127.0.0.1", 4000).await.unwrap();
    let (mut read, mut write) = tokio::io::split(tsport);
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        println!("read worker started");
        'read_loop: loop {
            // sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
            let packet = match read_packet(&mut read).await {
                Ok(packet) => packet,
                Err(err) => {
                    eprintln!("Transport read packet error: {:?}", err);
                    break 'read_loop;
                }
            };
            println!("read packet{:?}", packet);
        }
        println!("read worker stoped");
    });
    let _ = tokio::spawn(async move {
        println!("write worker started");
        'writeloop: loop {
            // sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
            let data = vec![0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4];
            if let Err(er) = write.write_all(&data).await {
                eprintln!("Transport write packet error: {:?}", er);
                break 'writeloop;
            }
            println!("send packet success.");
        }
        println!("write worker stoped");
    })
    .await;
}
```

Comment: hi, If there are multiple implementations of transport, not just TcpStream, how can I use tokio:: io:: split instead

Comment: @Hai.Xu I don't understand what you mean by this.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I may have TCP/websocket/TLS when implementing transport. How can I handle multiple such situations? When using other languages, I will use multiple classes with the same API to implement. The code above returns TcpStream when creating a transport. How can I handle this situation

Comment: @Hai.Xu I still don't understand what you mean. You want to wrap the `TcpStream`, or the `ReadHalf` or `WriteHalf`, in structs? You can do this.

Comment: Yes, it should be what you understand. I want an object that can be directly separated, possibly not TcpStream, Perhaps it would be more understandable to say so. If the method new_tcp_transport returns not a TcpStream, but a type: Box<dyn Transport + Send + Sync>.

Comment: @Hai.Xu This is indeed a problem. You're better off returning two objects, `(Box<dyn TraponsportRead>, Box<dyn TransportWrite>)`.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much for your patient response. Wish you good luck!